# issue counting number of rows and columns in a CSV file with C++

Tags: c++, csv

this is the code im working with, this is the first part, I want to get/count the number of rows and columns in the file, the program successfully counted the number of rows.... But the number of columns is wrong, it says its 0 when its suppose to be 26; can someone help me identify the issue?

```
// variable declarations
string LineA;
int x;
int col = 0;
int row = 0;
int arrayA[10][10] = { {0} };

//open files
fs_chola.open("CHOLAWCODE.xlsx"); //i'll convert this file to .csv later
if (fs_chola.is_open()){
    cout << "chola file successfully opened\n";
}
if (fs_chola.fail()){
    cerr << "file(chola) not found!"<< endl;
}
fs_master_menu.open("master_menu.csv");
if (fs_master_menu.is_open()){
    cout << "master menu file successfully opened\n";
}
if (fs_master_menu.fail()){
    cerr << "file(master menu) not found! " << endl;
}

// read file
while (fs_master_menu.good()){

    while (getline(fs_master_menu, LineA)){
        istringstream streamA(LineA);

        while (streamA >>x){
            arrayA[row][col] = x;
            col++;
        }
        row++;
    }
}
cout << "done \n";

// show colums and rows (checking to make sure everything is right)
cout << "number of rows: " << row << endl;
cout << "number of columns: " << col << endl;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you see when debugging it?

Comment: Anyway, you should reset the `col` variable for each new `row`, otherwise you will write outside the `arrayA`. And then anything can happen.

Comment: @BoPersson

okay, i did what you suggested, set col = 0; to reset it but it doesnt seem to fix the issue, with and without col = 0; to reset, in the end, the output is still " number of columns: 0"

Comment: @FirstStep i dont get any errors, after execution/debugging, 
i get 
done
number of rows: 157650  
number of columns: 0